# Files edited through gvfs using Eclipse and NetBeans getting corrupted. gedit using smb works fine

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, netbeans, smb, gvfs

I'm facing a strange problem. My development machine was recently moved to Ubuntu. When I edit files situated in a network server (LAN) and then save, the files are getting corrupted. In all cases a few lines from the bottom portion of the source file is being copied/pasted twice. Like this:-

```
             .......................
            ......................
            <div class="corner_lt2"></div>

            <div class="corner_rt2"></div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

<? include("footer.php"); ?>
      <div class="clear"></div>
<? include("footer.php"); ?>
```

See how the footer and the previous line is copied twice.

In both Eclipse and NetBeans, I'm accessing the files like this:

```
/home/user/.gvfs/server1 on 192.168.1.5/MyProject/file.php
```

gedit works fine, which is accessing the files via smb.

The network server is running RedHat. Also there are other users editing the files through gvfs using both Eclipse and NetBeans and they say the haven't this problem.

Anyone knows any solutions or or workarounds?